# Check if two specific values appear in on same row in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table named 'users-events' which is a three column table consisting of id, user_id, event_id.

I'm trying to determine in php whether two specific values appear on the same row in the database to see whether a user is registered for an event.

For example, if the row was: x, 1, 1 It would mean user 1 is registered to event 1 so hide the register for event button and show the resign from event button.

Currently I have a really messy and non-functional concoction...

```
<?php 
    if(!mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM `users-events` WHERE event_id IN (".$_SESSION['uid'].")"))){
        ?>
    <input type="submit" class="button1" name="btn-register" value="Register for event">
    <?php }else{ ?>
        <input type="submit" class="button1" name="btn-resign" value="Resign from event">
    <?php } ?>
```

This is important as I also need the same thing so users can't register for the same event multiple times.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Save yourself a world of pain. Don't use '-' in a table/column identifier. And id appears to serve no purpose here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but that isn't interfering with anything here is it?

Comment: only my sense of calm and well-being.

Comment: @Reece. Do you have event id for this?. If yes change the sql query to SELECT user_id FROM `users-events` WHERE event_id = $eventId and user_id = $userId. This is just an example.

Comment: @ErFaiyazAlam Thanks, this helped a ton!

Comment: @ReeceMathieson. If my comment worked for you, you can vote up my comment.

Answer (score 0):

First query with all events for user. I think `$_SESSION['uid']` is User ID.

```
$events_query = "SELECT event_id FROM `users-events` WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['uid'];
```

Next execute this and save to array. And

```
if(array_key_exists($event_id,$event_user_array)){

}else{

}
```

Comment: Good! Please also consider switching to PDO or mysqli_ instead of depreacted mysql_

Comment: @isnisn I do not suggest using mysq_ . I only wrote what to do. mysql_ is not supported in PHP 7

Comment: it was meant for original poster

Comment: Ok :) Good suggestion

Comment: Im still confused with how to use this code.  It seems to be yielding the same results as my previous code...

Comment: I think I don't understand your vision. 

Why same records user 1 and event 1. What if user 2 has event 1 ?

Comment: Think of user_id and event_id as foreign keys, if user 2 should be able to register to event 1 as well as user 1, im looking for an algorithm that will be able to yeild a boolean result for whether a particular user is registered to a particular event, or more specifically, if the current user ($_SESSION['uid']) is registered to the currently viewed event ($eventid).

Comment: `select count(id) as count_event from FROM users-events where user_id = ".$userid." and event_id =  ".$eventid;`

Execute this to 1 row.

If $row['count_event'] == 0 then register ;

Comment: Supposedly that's invalid SQL syntax. *EDIT* You put two 'FROM's in there :P

Comment: @ReeceMathieson  Ok . I wrote this in comment not in IDE so it's normal that I didn't see my syntax. Your problem is solved now ?

Comment: If works in console have to work on page. Check you php code.
Code PHP:
`$sql = "select count(id) as count_event FROM users-events where user_id = ".$userid." and event_id = ".$eventid;`

`$r = mysql_query($sql);`
`$row = mysql_fetch_array($r);`
`if($row['count_event'] == 0)` ---

Answer (score 0):

So today I have learned you can use an AND clause in SQL.  Its times like this where i'm obviously a self-taught programmer.  I'm sure I would have been taught this in like lesson 1.

```
$regcheck = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM `users-events` WHERE user_id ='".$_SESSION['uid']."' AND event_id ='".$eventid."'"));
if(empty($regcheck)){ showregisterbutton(); }else{ showresignbutton(); }
```